# Cyrus IMAP: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Tags: ubuntu, imap, telnet, cyrus

I'm working on setting up a Cyrus 2.2 IMAP server on Ubuntu Server 9.04.

If I telnet from the server itself:

```
# telnet localhost imap
```

I get:

```
* OK IMAP Cyrus IMAP4 v2.2.13-Debian-2.2.13-14ubuntu3 server ready
```

Which is what I should be seeing. If I try from another machine on the network:

```
telnet 192.168.5.122 imap
```

I get:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

UPDATE: From /etc/cyrus.conf

```
# add or remove based on preferences
imap            cmd="imapd -U 30" listen="imap" prefork=0 maxchild=100
imaps           cmd="imapd -s -U 30" listen="imaps" prefork=0 maxchild=100
#pop3           cmd="pop3d -U 30" listen="pop3" prefork=0 maxchild=50
#pop3s          cmd="pop3d -s -U 30" listen="pop3s" prefork=0 maxchild=50
#nntp           cmd="nntpd -U 30" listen="nntp" prefork=0 maxchild=100
#nntps          cmd="nntpd -s -U 30" listen="nntps" prefork=0 maxchild=100
```

To the best of my knowledge, there is no firewall running on the box. I've tried restarting the saslauthd and cyrus2.2 daemons, with no effect.

What else can I try?

Comment: What is the output of netstat -tnlp ?

Comment: With an lsof -p <pid> you can find out, where this daemon is actually listening.

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

Try changing

`listen="imap"` to `listen="192.168.5.122:imap"`

I am pretty sure it should solve the issue.

Comment: Made the change and restarted cyrus, still can't connect though. Now I can't connect via localhost either!

Comment: Ok, looks like `listen="imap"` tells it to bind to all available IP addresses. 

Can you do "telnet 192.168.5.122 imap" from the *same* machine its running on?

Comment: No, "telnet 192.168.5.122 imap" returns connection refused.

Comment: OK, Changed it back to just listen="imap" and restarted, and now the connection seems to be working.

Comment: Ok, something is blocking it locally. Are you sure that you are running Cyrus as a standalone daemon and not the default inetd/xinetd way? Check your `/etc/inetd.conf` or `/etc/xinetd.d/<imapd>`. There is a possibility that it is blocking . Also, what does `ufw status` say?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was, but changing back to listen="imap" and restarting fixed the issue- I can connect remotely with telnet now. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure which answer to mark as the solution though...

Comment: Glad i could help. Probably this one :)

Comment: Yay! Now on to the next issue... Aren't servers fun? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your firewall is blocking it?

What does `iptables -vnL` say? 
Also your inetd/xinetd may not be allowing connections from anything other than localhost.

Comment: "bash: iptables: command not found"

I'm pretty sure there's no firewall installed.

Comment: See if there is something in `/etc/default/cyrus2.2
`

Comment: Also check `/etc/cyrus.conf` for these lines:

`# add or remove based on preferences
  imap          cmd="imapd" listen="192.168.0.1:imap" prefork=0
  imaplocal     cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd-local.conf" listen="127.0.0.1:imap" prefork=0
  imaps         cmd="imapd -s" listen="192.168.0.1:imaps" prefork=0
  imapslocal    cmd="imapd -C /etc/imapd-local.conf" listen="127.0.0.1:imaps" prefork=0`

Comment: I've added that section to my original question above. It's easier to read that way ;) It's similar by not exactly what you specified.

Comment: Also, the /etc/default/cyrus2.2 file DOES exist. What am I looking for?

Comment: You'll probably not have iptables in your PATH - run "/sbin/iptables --list -n", as root, to absolutely confirm that there is no firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the authentication deamon is also running.  Had this problem with courier imap and it turned out that the authentication wasn't running.